# A Fast Power Grid Frequency Estimation Approach Using Frequency Shift Filtering

Tags: matlab, estimation, time-frequency, parameter-estimation

I have read the paper [A Fast Power Grid Frequency Estimation Approach Using Frequency Shift Filtering](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8610231).

I want to prove it using a numerical example, I have problem how to calculate the `hp(n)` values,

Let's suppose that I have a sample signal which I have sampled with an ADC and for simplicity I will use Matlab to make the signal. (the signal has a 50.1HZ frequency) and I want to estimate it with this paper approach,

```
fs = 12800;                    % Sampling frequency (samples per second)
dt = 1/fs;                   % seconds per sample
StopTime = 0.02;             % 20 mili seconds or a 1 full cycle of 50Hz AC
t = (0:dt:StopTime-dt)';     % seconds
F = 50.1;                    % Sine wave frequency (hertz)
X = sin(2*pi*F*t);           % Generate sine wave
```

Now How should I calculate the `hp(n)` values using MATLAB?
Finally I should convolve the result with this sample sin wave to get 50.1 Hz estimation.

Comment: The article seems to be behind a paywall...

Comment: From the look of it, they seem to perform the *Park* transform with a fixed-frequency (50 Hz) in your case.

Since, the frequency is not exactly 50 Hz, the d-q signals won't be DC but will have a frequency of f - 50 Hz or 0.1 Hz in your case.

Comment: Thanks, then How should I generate the H and do convolution?

Comment: you can check out the Paper in here https://sci-hub.do/10.1109/tpwrs.2019.2892599

Comment: The filter is a moving-average, h[n] is explained on page 2 $h_{av}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically they cascade moving-average filters, or CAF.

a Moving-average filter has the following coefficients

$h_{av}(m) = 1/M, m = 0, 1.. M-1$

In Matlab it would look like this

```
h = ones(1,M)./M;
y = filter(h,1,x);
```

If you want to cascade three moving-average filters

```
h = ones(1,M)./M;
y1 = filter(h,1,x);
y2 = filter(h,1,y1);
y3 = filter(h,1,y2);
```

M should be equal to the number of samples per period. So if your frequency is approximately 50 Hz and your sampling frequency is 12800 Hz then M = 256;.

Edit : I modified your script to make it work. There were 2 problems, first of all you only processed 256 samples, your couldn't measure anything significant because the transient response of your 3 cascaded filters is 768 samples long. Secondly, you filtered the reference and not your complex signal...

```
clear
clc
%ADC sin wave, it represent the data that I have captured with the ADC
%and want to estimate the frequency
ADCsin = dsp.SineWave(1,50.1);
ADCsin.ComplexOutput = false;
ADCsin.SampleRate  = 12800;
ADCsin.SamplesPerFrame = 12800;
ADC = ADCsin();
plot(ADC);
grid on
hold on

%ref sin wave with 50Hz complex value
Refsin = dsp.SineWave(1,50);
Refsin.ComplexOutput = true;
Refsin.SampleRate  = 12800;
Refsin.SamplesPerFrame = 12800;
ref = Refsin();
plot(imag(ref))

%calculating  xs
xs = ref .* ADC;

%calculate the CAF
M = 256;
h = ones(1,M)./M;
y1 = filter(h,1,xs);
y2 = filter(h,1,y1);
y3 = filter(h,1,y2);


%calculating the final result
Fest = 50 - (angle(y3(end)) - angle(y3(end-1))) * 12800/(2*pi)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the info, so how hp is calculated, so we do the convolution and estimate that this example X signal has 50.1Hz frequency?

Comment: No, the rest of the processing required is explained in the paper. You need to shift the frequency before filtering.

Comment: Dear Ben thanks for the feedback, would you please tell me How to do it in matlab? I'm a bit confused how to do it. thanks

Comment: How should I do it in matlab?

Comment: Which part specifically?

Comment: Basically you demodulate your signal with a complex sinusoid. You will have a complex sinusoids with frequencies near 0 Hz and frequencies near 2*f (100 Hz or 120 Hz). You filter the data to remove the 2f components. Then, you extract the phase of the filtered complex sinusoid. The phase difference of 2 samples will give you the shifted frequency.

You add the shifted frequency to the frequency of the original complex sinusoid.

Comment: I want to write a matlab script to calculate the estimated frequency, so for example the output of this sample sin wave should be 50.1Hz, so we have made the sin wave, and as you told we have y1,y2 or y3, now how should I calculate the rest and estimate the frequency in matlab?

Comment: Post what you did so far and I'll try to help you.

Comment: I have generated the sine wave with these commands
fs = 12800;
dt = 1/fs;
StopTime = 0.02;
t = (0:dt:StopTime-dt)';
F = 50.1;
X = sin(2*pi*F*t);

Also I have Generated Y1 as you told like this
h = ones(1,256)./256;
y1 = filter(h,1, X);

Then I calculated the convolution of the X and y1 to determine the frequency
F = conv2(X, y1);
And now getting frequency from to samles of the F, like this
DF = ((F(1) - F(256)) * 256 * 50 )/ (2*pi*255)

So estimated f should be like this
Fest = 50 + DF;
Which is 50.0438 and it’s far from the 50.1 answer according to the paper results.

Comment: Ben, I do not know how to format the answer here, correctly, so I make a post on matlab community, https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/759459-fast-power-grid-frequency-estimation/?s_tid=mlc_lp_leaf

Comment: I'm really need some help, would someone please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to wait out the filter transient...

Comment: You cascade 3 moving-average filters with 256 taps each. The transient length will be 768 samples.

Flush the first 768 samples at the output of the filter, and then estimate the frequency.

Comment: Thanks Ben, would you please tell me how to do a complex Sin wave in MATLAB and also how to flus the 768 samples?

Comment: Ben
Thanks for your help, the code works as expected, Now I want to know is there a way to combine all the 3 filters into one filter, as the paper call it pre-computed filter, so that the filter need to be calculated only one time, I mean these lines of code %calculate the CAF M = 256; h = ones(1,M)./M; y1 = filter(h,1,xs); y2 = filter(h,1,y1); y3 = filter(h,1,y2);

Answer (score 0):

So, Now I have done a little bit more, Now I'm generating a complex reference sine wave,
The things that I have done are as follow

```
clear
clc
%ADC sin wave, it represent the data that I have captured with the ADC
%and want to estimate the frequency
ADCsin = dsp.SineWave(1,50.1);
ADCsin.ComplexOutput = false;
ADCsin.SampleRate  = 12800;
ADCsin.SamplesPerFrame = 256;
ADC = ADCsin();
plot(ADC);
grid on
hold on

%ref sin wave with 50Hz complex value
Refsin = dsp.SineWave(1,50);
Refsin.ComplexOutput = true;
Refsin.SampleRate  = 12800;
Refsin.SamplesPerFrame = 256;
ref = Refsin();
plot(imag(ref))

%calculating  xs
xs = ref .* ADC;

%calculate the CAF
M = 256;
h = ones(1,M)./M;
y1 = filter(h,1,ref);
y2 = filter(h,1,y1);
y3 = filter(h,1,y2);

%doing the actual final convolution
F = conv2(xs, y3);

%calculating the final result
Fest = 50 - (angle(F(4)) - angle(F(3)) * 256*50)/(2*pi*90)
```

the answer is clearly wrong! so what I have done wrong?

Comment: You're doing many things wrong.

For starters you filter only 256 samples with FIR samples that have 256 coefficients. You will always be in the transient response.

Secondly, why do you filter the reference 3 times? You need to filter xs with 3 cascaded moving-average filters.

I modified your script and it works, I get a frequency of 50.1 Hz.

Comment: Dear ben would you please share your code.